# "Ooops! Something bad happened!", are you going to fix this?

Tags: bug

I write most of my answers on Stack Overflow with akregator. Every time I submit an answer, the only response I get is a page saying "OOPS something bad happened!" and this cat in front of a laptop. It also says it's not your fault, but our fault.

When I submit answers to Stack Overflow, the answers are posted. But the first time I tried to submit this bug report, the question didn't even get posted.

So as you are already stating that this is your fault, are you going to fix it?

Comment: What browser? How do you even write in a feed reader?

Comment: I f I understand you correctly, you use the built-in browser of akregator for posting? Is this correct? If yes, I suggest: Get a real browser! And I will vote to close as too localized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your "browser" is mangling the cookies and/or response URLs.

Even though **this is not a supported browser**, it's interesting to hear about this, because we kept wondering what those bizarre errors in the error log were.

Answer (score 7):

Well, I think it only counts as Stack Overflow's fault if you're using the standard way of posting. The message is there because for the *vast* majority of people, that is the case.

If you're using some odd way of posting (from an RSS reader? very odd!) I think that firmly counts as *your* fault instead - or at least, if you can never post any answers, and clearly people using a browser *can* post answers, that's a pretty huge hint that it's your way of posting which is causing the problem.

Use a browser.

Comment: I am always wondered about this fact. Why does doing something different than the majority, mean doing it wrong.

Comment: It doesn't mean you are doing it wrong. It just means that you can't expect it to work and complain when it doesn't if you try to do something completely outside of the box.  There are just too many broken browsers out there to be able to support all of them without any gotchas.  Users of fringe browsers need to be aware that they may find some things that don't work as a result of their choice.

Comment: @johannes: Let's say it's pretty *likely* that it's something odd that your application is doing.

Comment: On the other hand, if stackoverflow isn't completely sure that it's their fault they shouldn't say so.

Comment: @gs: I think it's better to be reassuring in the vast majority of cases where it *will* be accurate than to give a more guarded but less friendly message.